# How to style Form elements using any UI Kit?

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, user-interface

I have a UI kit something like the on [this link](http://graphicriver.net/item/styllus-ui-kit-10/1865716).

And I would like to assign same Style to HTML form elements like radio buttons, selectbox, checkbox, textbox, textarea and others. What is the best way to apply styles to these Form elements so that they can look exactly like the one in the UI kit? Also if there is any javascript based plugin available for it, then please let me know.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

formalize is awesome. you can easily manipulate the styles http://formalize.me/

Answer (score 0):

You would have to be more specific, are you trying to start from scratch with some graphics that you downloaded or do you have some css to start with?

As a starting point I would probably start by selecting basic form elements such as input, textarea, select, and then applying shared styles to those elements and and then slowly cascade the styling down as needed with more specific targets such as "input[type="text"], input[type="submit"], etc...